# Batch only crashes when echo is off

Tags: batch-file, crash

I've been coding a lot with batch lately, and kept having issues with my script crashing, but when I removed the **@echo off**, it suddenly worked. But because I need the **@echo off**, I cant find any effective way to determine the problem. The fact that my script has almost 30K rows makes it hard to search for the problem, or to post the code here for you to search for it. So, has anyone any Idea what could cause this behaviour?

Comment: Describe how your script is crashing, then insert `pause` commands (preceded by a message, eg `echo got to place #1&pause`) at various points to isolate the point where the crash is occurring.

Comment: 30K rows? Do you mean 30K characters in one line, 30K lines or what? I couldn't understand how batch files work with 'rows'.